# How can i ignore attatched images with imap_fetchbody?

Tags: php, format, imap, email-attachments

I'm using a PHP script with the imap_fetchbody function to read an email account, but when I get a mail with an image attached, the whole message gets dirty. How can I get only the text part?
I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fetchstructure.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php

there are several very usefull examples in the comments below the documentation.